# Asyncio.sleep() seems to sleep forever

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio

I need to write function which adds object to array and deletes it after x seconds. I use asyncio.sleep for delay. Here is the code:

```
import asyncio


class Stranger: 
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address 


class Fortress:  
    def __init__(self, time_: int, attempts: int):
        self.time = time_ 
        self.attempts = attempts 
        self.strangers_list: list = []

    async def _handle_task(self, stranger):  
        self.strangers_list.append(stranger)
        index = len(self.strangers_list) - 1
        await asyncio.sleep(self.time)
        print('Woke up')
        self.strangers_list.pop(index)

    async def _create_handle_task(self, stranger): 
        task = asyncio.create_task(self._handle_task(stranger))
        print('Ran _handle_task')

    def handle(self, stranger): 
        asyncio.run(self._create_handle_task(stranger))


async def main(tim):
    await asyncio.sleep(tim)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Fortress(2, 4)
    s = Stranger('Foo street, 32')
    f.handle(s)
    asyncio.run(main(3))
```

Theoretically, the output might be:

```
Ran _handle_task
Woke up
```

But it is just `Ran _handle_task`
What's the problem that interferes program to come out of the sleep?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems the coroutine did come out of the sleep since it printed "Waking up...."  after awaiting the sleep. Edit: Note it printed "Ran _handle_task" before it printed "Waking up..." because the coroutine slept before printing "Waking up..." and the create_task did not wait for that sleep.

Comment: `asyncio.run(main(3))` it will just sleep because `main()` does only that. You have to reimplement main to do the actual calls to your object. Also, you create a task, but no one is executing it.

Comment: @alec_djinn main() should not do anything else. It was created just to wait a bit more time than provided in time_ parameter of Fortress class. Task should be working in background. Sorry for possible misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a task, which is an example of an `awaitable` in asyncio.
You need to `await` the `task` in your `_create_handle_task` method.

```py
async def _create_handle_task(self, stranger): 
    task = asyncio.create_task(self._handle_task(stranger))
    
    await task 
    # ^blocks until the task is complete.
    
    print('Ran _handle_task')
```

Source: [asyncio docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)